# How to print response from binance API using python-binance

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.6, binance

Does anyone know how to print the JSON results from the Binance's API? I've been using this to `get_all_tickers` which returns all symbols and prices. I want to be able to select a certain symbol and price and display it live in the terminal continuously or until the user exits. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance).

my code:

```
url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'
response = reqs.get(url)        # To execute get request 
print(response.status_code)     # To print http response code  
print(response.content)
print(response.json)            # To print formatted JSON response
```

output:

```
200 
{ 
  "userId": 1, 
  "id": 1, 
  "title": "market data", 
  "completed": False 
}
```

Comment: Instead of printing `response.json`, assign it to some name, then you have a regular python object

Comment: I'm suspicious about `response.json` instead of `response.json()` (calling the function) but maybe I'm getting muddled with Flask